# How to find the derivative of inverse funtion

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$f(x) = 3x^3 + 4x^2 + 6x + 5$

$a=5$

Can someone please explain this step by step? I don't know where to start.

I tried using this formula, $(f^-1)'(a) = 1/ f '(f^-1(a))$ But I don't understand it.

Comment: Do you want to determine the derivative of $f^{-1}(x)$? What is $a$? What have you tried?

Comment: please put in enough effort for your question to be at least understood

Comment: I'm sorry, I was trying to use this formula (f^-1)'(a) = 1/ f ' (f^-1(a))

Comment: Hint: $f(0)=5$ and $f'>0$ so what is $f^{-1}(5)$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the formula you have provided, and note 
$$
f'(x)=9x^2+8x+6
$$
and note that 
$$
5=3x^3+4x^2+6x+5\implies x=0=f^{-1}(5)
$$
so, you plug in 
$$
(f^{-1})'(5)=\frac{1}{9x^2+8x+6\vert_0}=1/6
$$